# How do I generate the schema.graphql file when using Apollo Server?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

When using Apollo Server to write a GraphQL server, how can I run a command on the server to generate the `schema.graphql` file for the client to consume? Note: I'm not using the Apollo Client, I'm using Relay.

I know I can run the GraphQL playground and download it from there, but I want a command line that I can automate.

I'm searching for something similar to `rake graphql:schema:dump` when using [GraphQL Ruby](https://graphql-ruby.org/api-doc/1.11.1/GraphQL/RakeTask) which you can run on the server to generate the `schema.graphql`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use Apollo CLI for that. First install it:

```
npm install -g apollo
```

Then run this command as shown in the [docs](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling#apollo-clientdownload-schema-output):

```
apollo client:download-schema --endpoint=URL_OF_YOUR_ENDPOINT schema.graphql
```

The command will generate either the introspection result or the schema in SDL depending on the extension used for the output file.

Your `ApolloServer` instance does not expose the schema it creates, but you can also run an introspection query directly against the instance:

```
const { getIntrospectionQuery, buildClientSchema, printSchema } = require('graphql')
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server')

const apollo = new ApolloServer({ ... })
const { data } = await apollo.executeOperation({ query: getIntrospectionQuery() })
const schema = buildClientSchema(data)
console.log(printSchema(schema))
```

If you're passing an existing `GraphQLSchema` instance to Apollo Server, you can also just call `printSchema` on it directly.

Comment: I'm not using Apollo client... if the server is running, isn't that barely a curl/wget?

Comment: I'm not sure how what client you're using factors into this. You asked for a CLI command to run to get a server's schema in SDL and this is one way of doing that. You can't just use curl for that because that would only return the introspection result. You need a way to turn that into a GraphQLSchema object and then print it. There's other ways of doing that, but you specifically asked for a CLI command.

Comment: I was after a CLI command on the server that would generate the `schema.graphql` from the defined types, without needing to download anything. I updated my question to specify this. I'm sorry.

Comment: See edit. If you want to run that from the command line, you'll need to turn it into an npm script.

Comment: Does this work for federated schemas?

Comment: Suggested package has been deprecated

Comment: How to specify auhentication headers?

Answer (score 4):

The `apollo` package has been deprecated.

#### TLDR;

You can try to use `@graphql-codegen/schema-ast` and generate a schema to a separate file with the config:

```
generates:
  src/@generated/graphql.ts:
    # TS definitions, if any
  src/@generated/schema.graphql:
    plugins:
      - 'schema-ast'
```

#### Longer answer in case you struggle with a similar problem:

Our setup consists of `@apollo/client` and `@graphql-codegen/cli`. The latter one works with apollo studio schema (the `codegen.yml` supports it).

The problem we were trying to resolve was integrating [an `eslint` plugin](https://github.com/B2o5T/graphql-eslint), that doesn't support Apollo schema.

We ended up downloading and generating the schema locally using the `codegen` plugin, and then referencing it in `eslint`. Also we `gitignor`ed it