# Extract Apollo GraphQL schema

Tags: graphql, apollo

I can't find a way to extract the schema from an Apollo GraphQL project.

When it's deployed, I get a playground where I can test queries and download the schema in the UI, but I want to extract it in my deploy pipeline, to have the documentation updated in an S3 bucket on each commit to a repository main branch.

At the moment I cant find any commands to generate the schema without deploying my app to a lambda and going to the `/playground` path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I generate the schema.graphql file when using Apollo Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62483120/how-do-i-generate-the-schema-graphql-file-when-using-apollo-server)

Comment: Kinda did the same actually not completely the same but close. used 
pnpm apollo schema:download